Output is different than Stdout in Python
I'm new to programming and I'm trying Leetcode. The question asks to store the answer inside nums1. When I print nums1, the stdout shows the correct answer but the output is not the same?
enter image description here
class Solution(object):
    def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n):
        """
        :type nums1: List[int]
        :type m: int
        :type nums2: List[int]
        :type n: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """

        for x in range(n):
            nums1.remove(0)

        nums1 = nums1 + nums2
        nums1.sort()
        print(nums1)

This is what it shows:
enter image description here

Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's not really a question here, though at least it's obvious what you need help with. Check out [ask] for tips for future questions, like how to write a good title.

LeetCode only remembers the memory reference of the initial nums1 list, so if you update it using nums1 = nums1 + nums2, the original array won't be updated and instead a new reference is created. Weird, I know.
The solution to this is to use nums1.extend(nums2) which modifies the list in place instead of nums1 = nums1 + nums2.

To clarify, your code is not exactly the best solution here. I have only solved your problem of not being able to submit your answer. It must be admitted that I am anything but an expert in these algorithms, but @SIGHUP seems to be rather well-versed in this topic, so you could enquire him and/or read his answer, which probably displays right below this answer.

I don't know why this has become the accepted answer because it won't work. The nums1 list has n significant elements but has a length of m + n. If you extend that list you will retain the "padding" and its length will become m + 2 * n

@SIGHUP: The code removes the padding first. It does so in a horribly inefficient way, but it does remove the padding.

Yup, the code given does already remove the padding (although in a horribly inefficient way as stated by the commenter before me), but the post author is having problems with passing the result as output. In my opinion, only giving them the more correct solution (is out of scope of/doesn't answer) their question and disencourages OP to think about a more efficient solution since the code is spoonfed.

Could also use nums1 += nums2.

@ChesterChow Maybe you should provide a full solution as your answer in order to remove any misunderstanding about your suggestion.

@user2357112 There is no code in this "answer" that removes anything from anywhere

@SIGHUP: Because that code is already in the question itself, and this answer only says to change the nums1 = nums1 + nums2 line. The code that removes the padding would stay.

It's not LeetCode doing the remembering, it's Python. Secondly, nums1 = nums1 + nums2 isn't an update, it's an overwrite of the identifier, i.e. it makes a new list but calls it the same name as the original list. Lastly, there's nothing weird about it; it makes perfect sense once you understand the logic underlying it.
